# What is the fastest way to handle overflow on integer division/remainder without panic?

Tags: performance, rust

I'm still improving [overflower](https://github.com/llogiq/overflower) to handle integer overflow. One goal was to be able use `#[overflow(wrap)]` to avoid panics on overflow. However, I found out that the `.wrapping_div(_)` and `.wrapping_rem(_)` functions of the standard integer types do in fact panic when dividing by zero. Edit: To motivate this use case better: Within interrupt handlers, we absolutely want to avoid panics. I assume that the div-by-zero condition is highly unlikely, but we still need to return a "valid" value for some definition of valid.

One possible solution is saturating the value (which I do when code is annotated with `#[overflow(saturate)]`), but this is likely relatively slow (especially since other,more  operations are also saturated). So I want to add an `#[overflow(no_panic)]` mode that avoids panics completely, and is almost as fast as `#[overflow(wrap)]` in all cases.

My question is: What is the fastest way to return *something* (don't care what) without panicking on dividing (or getting the remainder) by zero?

Comment: *What is the fastest way to return something (don't care what)* — if the correctness of the program is not a concern, I'd suggest transforming all divisions / remainders to be the constant value `42`, regardless of arguments. This should improve the speed of most programs.

Comment: I think this question isn't Rust specific at all. I'd probably rephrase it (removing everything unrelated) and chose different tags. It seems like it could be best answered by x86 and assembly people...

Comment: 0 may be faster than 42 in some cases (`xor eax,eax` vs `mov eax,42`). Ditto Lukas.

Comment: I'm guessing that the fastest way would be to branch. `if y != 0 { x / y } else { 0 }`

Comment: @dtolnay a good point; I was mostly being silly because it seems like correctness not mattering shouldn't be true. ^_^ @Adrian no branch (and no division!) at all is even faster, thus why returning `0` all the time should be preferred.

Comment: I want a fast solution, but I also want it to be portable Rust. That's why I chose the tags.

Comment: What's the use case for silently returning a wrong answer instead of panicking?  Do you still want that if panic vs wrong answer doesn't affect the speed when that case isnt' hit?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: this isn't really a serious answer. It is almost certainly slower than the naive solution of using an if statement to check whether the divisor is zero.

```
#![feature(asm)]

fn main() {
    println!("18 / 3 = {}", f(18, 3));
    println!("2555 / 10 = {}", f(2555, 10));
    println!("-16 / 3 = {}", f(-16, 3));
    println!("7784388 / 0 = {}", f(7784388, 0));
}

fn f(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    let z: i32;
    unsafe {
        asm!(
            "
            test %ecx, %ecx
            lahf
            and $$0x4000, %eax
            or %eax, %ecx
            mov %ebx, %eax
            cdq
            idiv %ecx
            "
            : "={eax}"(z)
            : "{ebx}"(x), "{ecx}"(y)
            : "{edx}"
        );
    }
    z
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2fc811fe1ce2b2e25122dc7807f953b6&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Comment: You might as well include the various compiler versions, platforms, etc. that this solution supports. All of this contributes towards the evaluation of "fastest". For example, it's unlikely this will work on all the tier-1 platforms that Rust supports.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah, this isn't very portable, and requires a nightly compiler. However, it should work on any x86 system, which includes all of the tier-1 platforms.

Answer (score 1):

```
pub fn nopanic_signed_div(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    if y == 0 || y == -1 {
        // Divide by -1 is equivalent to neg; we don't care what
        // divide by zero returns.
        x.wrapping_neg()
    } else {
        // (You can replace this with unchecked_div to make it more
        // obvious this will never panic.)
        x / y
    }
}
```

This produces the following on x86-64 with "rustc 1.11.0-nightly (6e00b5556 2016-05-29)":

```
    movl    %edi, %eax
    leal    1(%rsi), %ecx
    cmpl    $1, %ecx
    ja  .LBB0_2
    negl    %eax
    retq
.LBB0_2:
    cltd
    idivl   %esi
    retq
```

It should produce something similar on other platforms.

At least one branch is necessary because LLVM IR considers divide by zero to be undefined behavior.  Checking for 0 and -1 separately would involve an extra branch.  With those constraints, there isn't really any other choice.

(It might be possible to come up with something slightly faster with inline assembly, but it would be a terrible idea because you would end up generating much worse code in the case of dividing by a constant.)

---

Whether this solution is actually appropriate probably depends on what your goal is; a divide by zero is probably a logic error, so silently accepting it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: You might as well include the assembly and the various compiler versions, platforms, etc. all of which will contribute towards the evaluation of "fastest". For example, what's the PPC assembly look like? Or maybe ARM?